# Realm manual install issues on iOS

Tags: ios, realm

I followed the instructions on the [doc page](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.6/) to get the manual install working. And it is working, however, when I tried to push to my repo, the repo rejected my push. I checked why this might be, and I found that there was a large file, 46 MB or so. This file is located at ios/Realm.framework/Realm

What is this file? And why is it 45,6 MB?
Why is the OSX Realm.framework only 2,8 MB while the iOS Realm.framework is 45 MB + ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ section of Realm docs](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa#how-big-is-the-realm-library):

> How big is the Realm library?
>
> Once your app is built for release, Realm should only add around 1MB to its size. The releases we distribute are significantly larger (~37MB for iOS & ~2.4MB for OSX) because they include support for more architectures (ARM, ARM64, x86 for the simulator) and some debug symbols, which will all be stripped by Xcode automatically when you build your app.

If you'd like to avoid bundling binary dependencies in your git repo, you should build Realm and other dependencies from source either manually (drag `Realm.xcodeproj` in your project) or with a tool like CocoaPods or Carthage, all of which are covered in the [Installation](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa#installation) section of Realm's docs.